# PropertyDescriptor undefined when using TS decorator

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-decorator

TS Decorator

```
function exampleDeco(): any {
  return function (
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) {
    console.log(descriptor?.value, "descriptor");
    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

Result:

```
undefined descriptor
```

Function used on

```
@exampleDeco()
public exampleFn = (
  ) => { console.log('function') }
```

I don't know why it's logging undefined in the decorator.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the use of TS decorator on the arrow function `()=>{}`. It will work just fine if you use it on a normal JS function. Not sure why it is behaving like this though.